# Double-role in blender

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

Is there any way to achieve a *[double-role](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_role)* effect using Blender?

By double-role, I mean the effect used in films for showing the same object (most likely a person) two or more times in a single frame.

I have two footage scenes and want to merge them, like if I shoot a video when I am at the left end of the frame and then again when I am at the right end of the frame (camera is steady and has not moved), then I want to merge it into a single clip where I am seen two times, once at the right end once at the left end.

I know that Blender is not suited for such kinds of video editing, but still, is there any technique or a workaround that can achieve by editing video footage through the VSE.

Comment: please show a screenshot how the effect should look like

Comment: Like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_role. It is not actually an image, but a Wikipedia article about the same

Comment: So why can't you just copy the object and move it a bit...!? then you have two times the same object....

Comment: I think they mean in the VSE/Composite

Comment: An example of a dual role is Justin Roiland playing both Rick Sanchez and Morty Smith in a single production "Rick and Morty". He is a voice actor for both roles, as it's an animated series. This is to prove that "double role" is not related to Blender. However, if you want to mimic some kind of movie trickery where one actor is playing multiple characters simultaneously, then that's just a matter of merging two strips using masking.

Comment: Another example of a dual role is the tv series [Orphan Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_Black) in which the main actress plays a dozen clone characters. How is this related to the VSE? Do you have 2 footage scenes and want to merge them?

Comment: @Blunder, yes, like if I shoot a video when I am at the left end of the frame and then again when I am at the right end of the frame (camera is steady and has not moved), then I want to *merge* it into a single clip where I am seen two times, once at the right end once at the left end.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, that is exactly what I intend to do. But masking each frame would be extremely tiresome.

Comment: The technique to have same actor appear twice in a frame in a frame is  [Split Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_screen_(video_production)) _The simplest technique is to lock down the camera and shoot the scene twice, with one "version" of the actor appearing on the left side, and the other on the right side. The seam between the two splits is intended to be invisible, making the duplication seem realistic_  _ie_ film it twice, butt the two halves together in VSE.   As mentioned it is achieved with compositing with the advent of  "digital technology"

Comment: Have a look here: [Default Cube: Master of hide and seek](https://youtu.be/E3lQSadaWd0). It's basically what Markus von Broady and batFINGER described: Split screen, steady camera, masking, and merging (frozen frame + actor). In your case there would be "two" actors.

Comment: @Blunder, that is exactly what I wanted! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I finally found out a way! It is mainly based on [this video by Default Cube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3lQSadaWd0) and the discussion in the comments, thanks to @Blunder and @batFINGER.

(For the explanation, I have used rendered video clips as I did not have any actual footage lying around.)

Basically, the process of double-role would be to have two video clips with the *duplicate* person once in each clip, and they should be confined two a particular area, such that they are not to be overlapped or interacting in any way.

The two clips I used: (Please forgive my art skills)

[image]

[image]

Now, we add both the videos into the compositing tab and use the following node setup:

[image]

Remember to set the value of the number of frames to the total number of frames of the video clips (in my case, this is 50).

Now, open the *Image Editor* and go the *Viewer Node* the following way:

[image]

You will now see the output of the viewer node in the *Image Editor* tab.

Then go to the **Mask** mode here:

[image]

Then click the `+ New` button.
Now Ctrl-Click on the image to select an area where the *other-duplicate-character-of-the-other-clip-is-confined-to* and remember to check the *Cyclic* option.

[image]

Finally, go back to the compositing tab and then in the *Mask* node, select the *F Mask* option.

All the work is now done!!
Just render the final video and you are good to go!

My final output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Consider an edit, IMO  [split screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_screen_(video_production)) is the name of one "technique" used to have actors playing a  [dual / double role](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_role) in same frame.  Can be in a dual role without ever appearing in same frame.

Answer (score 2):

In the VSE, you place the two clips on top of each other and then in the top one you crop it and change compositing to Alpha Over:
[image]

Comment: An excellent technique if we want to apply the effect extremely quickly! But a drawback is that if the the area confined of the characters is not exactly rectangular, then this method fails...

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to answer how it could be done in the VSE, since you asked about that specifically. Btw. you can also use masks in the VSE to get a non-linear split area. Anyway, hopefully some day it'll be possible to just roundtrip a vse strip in the compositor, so the workflows can be merged.

Comment: .. well worth a UV